# Calculate a count of groupby rows that occur within a rolling window of days in Pandas

Tags: python, pandas

I have the following dataframe:

```
import pandas as pd
#Create DF
d = {'Name': ['Jim','Jim','Jim', 'Jim','Jack','Jack'], 
     'Date': ['08/01/2021','27/01/2021','05/02/2021','10/02/2021','26/01/2021','20/02/2021']}

              
df = pd.DataFrame(data=d)
df['Date'] = pd.to_datetime(df.Date,format='%d/%m/%Y')
df
```

[image]

I would like to add a column (to this same dataframe) calculating the how many have occurred in the last 28 days grouped by `Name`. Does anyone know the most efficient way to do this over 200,000 rows of code? with about 1000 different `Name`'s?

The new column values should be `1,2,3,3,1,2`. Any help would be much appreciated! Thanks!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Set the index of dataframe to `Date`, then group the frame by `Name` and apply `rolling` `count` with a closed window having offset of `28 days`

```
df['count'] = df.set_index('Date')\
                .groupby('Name', sort=False)['Name']\
                .rolling('28d', closed='both').count().tolist()
```

---

```
   Name       Date  count
0   Jim 2021-01-08    1.0
1   Jim 2021-01-27    2.0
2   Jim 2021-02-05    3.0
3   Jim 2021-02-10    3.0
4  Jack 2021-01-26    1.0
5  Jack 2021-02-20    2.0
```

Comment: Thanks @Shubham Sharma. Im getting this error `pandas.core.base.DataError: No numeric types to aggregate`. Any ideas?

Comment: @SOK What is your pandas version?

Comment: Ah `1.0.5` could that be the reason?

Comment: Thanks! I just needed to upgrade my `pandas` version